# How to create Locator[] hierarchies?

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I'd like to 'parent' Locators to one another, ideally organized in any arbitrary tree.

The simplest case:  If I have two Locators, A and B, then moving A will move both together, but moving B will only move that one.

Any simple suggestions?

Comment: Hi Cuboid! It's nice to get good answers, isn't it? Now, you may want to start contributing to the site trying to answer questions (it is a good exercise!) and also _accepting_ some answers given on your questions. If you don't know how accepting works, just ask :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not as fancy as belisarius' solution, but here's my approach. To store the tree, I'm using nested lists, so for example

```
tree = {1, {2}, {3}, {4, {5}, {6}}}
```

would define a tree with root `1` and children are `2`, `3`, and `4`, where node `4` has children `5` and `6`. From this we can construct a list of nodes and for each node a list of descendants:

```
nodelist[tree_] := Union[Flatten[tree]];
descendants[tree_] := nodelist[tree] /. 
   Flatten[MapIndexed[#1 -> Flatten@tree[[Sequence @@ Most[#2]]] &, tree, {-1}]];
```

To construct a list of edges from the tree you can do something like

```
toEdges[{root_}] := {}
toEdges[{root_, p : {__} ..}] := (Sow[{root, #[[1]]}]; toEdges[#]) & /@ {p};
edgelist[tree_] := Reap[toEdges[tree]][[2, 1]];
```

Finally, we construct a list of `Dynamic`s which will be used for dynamically updating the coordinates of the nodes. Here `pt` is a dummy function.

```
dynamics[tree_, pt_] := MapThread[Function[{ind, dec},
    Dynamic[pt[ind], {(crds0 = Transpose[pt /@ dec] - #) &,
       (MapThread[(pt[#1] = #2) &, {dec, Transpose[crds0 + #]}]) &,
       None}]], 
    {nodelist[tree], descendants[tree]}];
```

**Usage**

Consider an arbitrary tree `tree` whose nodes have coordinates `crds`

```
tree = {1, {2}, {3, {4}, {5, {6}, {7}}}, {8, {9}, {10}}};
crds = AbsoluteOptions[#, VertexCoordinates][[2]] &@
   Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ edgelist[tree], GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"];
```

Then you could do something like

```
DynamicModule[{pt, edges, nodes, dyn},
 dyn = dynamics[tree, pt];
 edges = edgelist[tree];
 nodes = nodelist[tree];
 Evaluate[pt /@ nodes] = crds;
 Graphics[{Arrow[Dynamic[pt /@ #]] & /@ edges, Locator /@ dyn},
  PlotRange -> ({Min[#] - 1, Max[#] + 1} & /@ Transpose[crds])]]
```

Answer (score 16):

### With an arbitrary locator dependency tree

**Updated** [Now the sub-blocks move as one piece](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1DEtRxLsKM) (per @RM request).

Lets first generate a dependency tree and calculate a few values for future use:

```
(*A dependency graph template*)
g[ns_, treeOrder_, data_] := KaryTree[ns, treeOrder, VertexLabels -> 
    Table[i -> Placed[data[[i]] // TableForm, Before], {i, ns}], ImagePadding -> 40, 
    VertexStyle -> Table[i -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[i]], {i, ns}],
    VertexSize -> Medium, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexCoordinates -> vc, ImageSize -> 500];

ns = 10;(*Number of nodes*)
(*Generate a Random dependencies Tree*)
treeOrder = RandomInteger[{2, 5}];
ktt = g[ns, treeOrder, RandomReal[1, {ns, 2}]];
(*Store some values for using them later in the dynamic constructs*)
vc = PropertyValue[{ktt, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ VertexList[ktt];
(*Plot Range*)
pr = {Min@# - 1, Max@# + 1} & /@ Transpose@vc;
(*dependency list for each node*)
voc = Reverse /@ (VertexOutComponent[ktt, #, Infinity] & /@ VertexList[ktt]);
inD = False;(*To control the firing of events, due to a bug in Locator/Dynamic*)
```

Now the main dynamic code:

```
DynamicModule[{n = ns, data = vc, dataPrsrv = vc},
 Framed@Column[{
    (*Draw locators and drag the dependency tree*)
    Dynamic[Framed@Show[
       Table[With[{i = i},
         Graphics[Locator[
           (*Each locator drags its dependency tree*)
           Dynamic[data[[i]],(* 3 funcs for the drag follow {start, active, end}*)
            {If[! InD, (dataPrsrv = data); InD = True] &,
             (data[[i]] = #; 
             ((data[[#]] = dataPrsrv[[#]] + (data[[i]] - dataPrsrv[[i]])) & /@ voc[[i]])) &, 
             (InD = False) &}],
           Graphics[{ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[i]], Disk[]}], ImageSize -> 20],
          PlotRange -> pr]], {i, ns}], ImageSize -> 300]],
    (*Draw the tree and update coordinates*)
    Dynamic@g[ns, treeOrder, data]}, Center]]
```

Chinese instruction manual:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: very nice! One improvement would be to be able to see the dependent locators move as the parent is dragged

Comment: +1 Pro answer, perhaps you should be yellow instead \\[FilledRightTriangle]

Comment: @R.M Now they do. :)

Answer (score 11):

I would do it by introducing as a third variable the displacement between A and B, and then using `Dynamic`'s second argument to update B when A is moved:

```
a = {0, 0}; b = {0.5, 0.5}; db = b - a;
Show[
 Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[a, (a = #; b = # + db;) &], Background -> Red],
 Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[b, (b = #; db = # - a;) &], Background -> Blue],
 PlotRange -> 2
 ]
Dynamic@a
Dynamic@b
```

Comment: +1 for two this works great! Any ideas for the `ideally organized in any arbitrary tree` part of the question?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rather short example of a potential way of getting this functionality. Initially we need to decide on a structure for the tree. I'm going with simply a list of lists type tree, where the first element of each list is assumed to be it's head. Except at the very first level, where each node is considered a child.

```
 tree = {{0,1}, {{0, 2}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 4}}, {{0, 3}, {1,3}, {{1, 4}, {3, 3}}}};
```

Having this structure we can apply a function to each leaf by calling; `Map[f, tree, {-2}]`. Now the trick is just to define a function that will update the tree such that if we change `tree[[2,1]]`, both `tree[[2,1]]` and `tree[[2,2]]` are updated. First I define a function that will map the change out over all elements under a given level:

```
SetAttributes[updateTree, HoldFirst]
updateTree[tree_, newposition_, indices__] := 
 tree[[indices]] = Map[# + (newposition - tree[[indices, 1]]) &, tree[[indices]], {-2}];
```

Then I define a new dynamic wrapper that will insert this updating function for any element having indexes ending in 1.

```
SetAttributes[treeDynamic, HoldAll]
 treeDynamic[tree_[[indices__]]] := Dynamic[tree[[indices]]]
 treeDynamic[tree_[[indices__, 1]]] := 
           Dynamic[tree[[indices, 1]], updateTree[tree, #, indices] &]
```

Then it's just a matter of mapping this wrapper over the tree and putting it into locators, note that I pass the index through an anonymous function in order for the pattern to match even though `treeDynamic` has `HoldAll`

```
 MapIndexed[Locator[treeDynamic[tree[[##]]]] & @@ #2 &, tree, {-2}] // Graphics
```